# echo p tag along with isset function condition in yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2

I want to echo `p` tag with class in php echo along with isset function new to php please help

here is the hmtl code with php:-

```html
<p class="titlemems"><?php echo (isset($value['sixthDiv']) ? $value['sixthDiv'] : ''); ?></p>
```

Comment: Where is your `p` tag? In model/controller or in view file. If `p` tag is in view then it's already displayed plus if your `$value['sixthDiv']` is empty then you will not see p tag but it's available in html. You can check by inspect element in browser and you have used `isset()` on whole element.

Answer (score 1):

This will print `p` tag only when `sixthDiv` isset.

```
<?php if(isset($value['sixthDiv'])) : ?>
     <p class="titlemems"> <?= $value['sixthDiv'] ?> </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great Works ..Thanks 
I would like to learn more things from you

Comment: @user3021146. No problem, You can find my contact  details in profile ;). Mark as accepted so it will help other people too.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the way to do it in yii2:

```
<?php echo yii\helpers\Html::tag(
    'p', 
    array_key_exists('sixthDiv', $value) ? $value['sixthDiv'] : '',
    array('class' => 'titlemems'));
?>
```

Comment: Great Work Thanks
I am using this in for each loop where sixthDiv is the associated part of array, due to for each loop the data is coming in associated array based on the value as key, but i dont want to call this p tag for others. well i am getting blank p tag where sixthDiv is not defined.

Please help if you got my point ?..

Comment: @user3021146 you don't want to print `p` tag when `sixthDiv` is not set?